# Pass a query string from the parent URL to a page viewer web part

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, query-string

This may be a simple question for SP2010, I am trying to get the query string from a page url and pass it to the url of a page viewer web part.

https://mysite.com/subsite/default.aspx?TeamID=X

The content in the page viewer webpart comes from a different site, but needs the TeamID.

https://othersite.com/page.htm?TeamID=X

I can set the query string manually in the page viewer url, but this is something that will be replicated many times, and I really want to find a way to set up the page viewer and not have to edit it each time I replicate the page.

Thanks in advance,

KB

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by JS. There are some libraries for URL parsing to get value from URL. Then you can append that value to IFRAME's SRC attribute in your page. IFRAME is generated by page view webpart.